# jQuery get img src within a href on click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, image

I have this HTML / PHP code that displays multiple images.

```
     <div class="product-other-images">
                  <?php
                  for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($productImages); $i++)
                  {
                      echo '<a id="alternate-image" href="#"';
                      if($i == 0)
                        echo 'class="active"';
                      echo '><img alt="' . $productName . '" src="' . $productImages[$i][1] . '"></a>';
                  }
                  ?>
              </div>
```

When you click the a href, I want to select the src from the img on the inside. So far I have this code which works when I click the a href.

```
    var Item = function () {
return {
    init: function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('a').click(function () {
                if ($(this).prop('id') == 'alternate-image')
                {
                    var href = $(this).attr('href');
                    alert(href);
                }
            });
        });
    }
};

}();
```

I need to take the src from the image and change the main display image of another img src.

Should I just make the img src the jQuery trigger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `img` is a child of the `a` element so

```
$('a').click(function () {
    if (this.id == 'alternate-image') {
        var src= $(this).find('img').attr('src');
        alert(src);
    }
});
```

---

You are creating the elements in a loop, so you are creating multiple elements with the same id that is not a valid html structure as id of an element must be unique.

In your case instead of using `alternate-image` as id use it as a class then use class selector to target those elements like

```
$('a.alternate-image').click(function () {
    var href = $(this).find().attr('href');
    alert(href);
});
```

then

```
<div class="product-other-images">
  <?php
  for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($productImages); $i++)
  {
      echo '<a class="alternate-image" href="#"';
      if($i == 0)
        echo 'class="active"';
      echo '><img alt="' . $productName . '" src="' . $productImages[$i][1] . '"></a>';
  }
  ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't duplicate ID's in a  page so change the id to class.

Then you can target the elements with the class as selector:

```
$('.alternate-image').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();// prevent default behavior of <a>
   var src = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
})
```